# segmentation fault pytest on shapely.geometry.box()

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, pytest, shapely

The following code fails when ran using `pytest` with the note "Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault"

```py
from shapely import geometry
def test_geometry_box(self) -> None:
    geom = geometry.box(*[1, 2, 3, 4])
```

However, when I run it directly (not using pytest) in a standalone file it works just fine

```py
from shapely import geometry
geom = geometry.box(*[1, 2, 3, 4])
```

My shapely version is '1.8.4' installed via poetry with the line `Shapely = "^1"`.

Any insight into what might be causing this code to fail specifically in the pytest run would be valuable.

This is the stack trace:

```bash
.../test.py Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Thread 0x000000030a67f000 (most recent call first):
  File ".../threading.py", line 316 in wait
  File ".../threading.py", line 581 in wait
  File ".../site-packages/tqdm/_monitor.py", line 60 in run
  File ".../threading.py", line 980 in _bootstrap_inner
  File ".../threading.py", line 937 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00000002045dce00 (most recent call first):
  File ".../site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 539 in geos_polygon_from_py
  File ".../site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 261 in __init__
  File ".../site-packages/shapely/geometry/geo.py", line 64 in box
  File "/test.py", line 55 in test_geometry_box
  File ".../site-packages/_pytest/python.py", line 192 in pytest_pyfunc_call
  File ".../site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File ".../site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File ".../site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File ".../site-packages/_pytest/python.py", line 1761 in runtest
  File ".../site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 166 in pytest_runtest_call
  File ".../site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File ".../site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File ".../site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File ".../site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 259 in <lambda>
  File ".../site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 338 in from_call
  File ".../site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 258 in call_runtest_hook
  File ".../site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 219 in call_and_report
  File ".../site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 130 in runtestprotocol
  File ".../site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 111 in pytest_runtest_protocol
  File ".../site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File ".../site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File ".../site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File ".../site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 347 in pytest_runtestloop
  File ".../site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File ".../site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File ".../site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File ".../site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 322 in _main
  File ".../site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 268 in wrap_session
  File ".../site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 315 in pytest_cmdline_main
  File ".../site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39 in _multicall
  File ".../site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80 in _hookexec
  File ".../site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265 in __call__
  File ".../site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 164 in main
  File ".../site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 187 in console_main
  File ".../pytest", line 8 in <module>
zsh: segmentation fault  pytest
```

Comment: It looks like you’re running with threading? How are you invoking the test? And how did you install your environment?

Comment: The test is being evoked simply with `pytest`. And we presuppose that the files are in a tests folder and file/class/method names start with 'test'. We install first by making an empty conda environment (seems silly but required for other aspects of the codebase), then poetry install where the pyproject.toml has 'Shapely = "^1"'

Comment: are you installing pytest the same way? or is it possible pytest is on a different env?

Comment: I've checked the `pip freeze`/`poetry show` and it seems that I'm evoking the pytest in this environment. I've also tried `poetry run pytest` and `python -m pytest`

Comment: Hmm not sure how to help further then. This certainly doesn’t happen for me. If you’re able to provide a full install spec with pinned versions which reproduce the error that would be helpful. Does this happen if you install with conda or just poetry?

Comment: I was able to determine the root cause. Added an answer to close the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the reason the test fails is because I import Affine in an `__init__.py` well before we reach the test. A minimum reproducible example would really be:

```py
from rasterio import Affine  # This should be imported second
from shapely import geometry


def test() -> None:
    geom = geometry.box(*[1, 2, 3, 4])
```

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/383) outlines more details.